# Philosopher that highlights that identity is made by societal standards?

Tags: history-of-philosophy, social-ethics

I'm currently writing an essay on social media and its toxic effects on our sense of identity. Would you know of any philosophers that believe that our identity is constructed by society's standards? Thanks :)

Comment: Identity is inherently social. The idea that social role influences identity is covered in sociology, among others.

Comment: You'll have to read the standard authors on self, self-image, and authenticity in order to be able to make an argument on the limits between self as a trait and self as a socially influenced structure. Like Frankfurt, for example. We cant take it upon us to think that through for you, although it sounds like an interesting essay topic.

Comment: That being said, one of the earliest philosophical books on social roles, their relation to personhood, and their behavioural limits is Plessner's *Laughing and Crying*. Also, type "self social media" in scholar.google.com and you get plenty to work with.

Comment: Certain psychologists study these phenomena. Lacan's "mirror stage" proposes that one's unitary identity is constructed socially when one starts using the term "I". I don't know how much that will help you though.